# Python Tkinter photo is not showing

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My goal is to show the photo but it's not showing.

```
#import tkintter

    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.font import Font
    from PIL import ImageTk,Image
    root = Tk()

#window title

    root.title("Ad-hoc Networks Attendance System")
    
#Create topframe on root window

    topframe=Frame(root)

 #create custom font for my company
  

      my_font=Font(family="Rekha",size=30,weight="bold",slant="italic")
        #create label on root window
        label=Label(root,text="Ad-hoc Networks Attendance System",font=my_font,foreground="#283142").pack()
        #pack topframe on top side
        topframe.pack(side=TOP)
    
#Create bottomframe with bottom side
  

       bottomframe=Frame(root)
    
#create leftframe in bottomframe with left side

    leftframe=Frame(bottomframe,bg='black')
    #create a canvas for image on leftframe
    canvas=Canvas(leftframe,width=627,height=663)
    canvas.pack()

#photo for canvas with photo path here is the part that when i run my code the photo wont show 
   

 

    photo=PhotoImage(file='gecap.png')
        #create position of canvas and image start at NW
        canvas.create_image(50,10,image=photo,anchor=NW)
        leftframe.pack(side=LEFT)
    
#Create rightframe in bottomframe with right side

   

     rightframe=Frame(bottomframe,padx=50)
        rightframe.pack(side=RIGHT)
        #Set window geometry width 1210 and height 750 and open position on screen left to 150 and top to 150
        root.geometry("1210x750+150+150")
        #stable main window on infinity time
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code looks ok to me. Are there any errors? Are you running this inside another function? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: could this just be a path issue, is gecep.jpg in the python working directory?

Comment: ahh i have no errors but the images is not showing when i try to run the code sorry im new at tkinter

Comment: i am using windows 10

Comment: @flutterrun is the image in the same folder as the code?

Comment: yes i put it in the same folder maybe im having a path issue cause i have no error but only the images is not showing

Comment: You forgot to `pack` bottom frame.

Comment: can you help me track that sir

Comment: That means you need to call `bottomframe.pack()`.

Comment: i finally got it sorry im just new in tkinter